# Отличия процесса и потока

Tags: java, любой-язык

Стандартный вопрос практически на каждом собеседовании по Java.

Какие отличия процесса (process) и потока (thread) ?

Comment: а зачем минусуем то? норм вопрос

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov "Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!" [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Процессы и потоки связаны друг с другом, но при этом имеют существенные различия.

Процесс — экземпляр программы во время выполнения, независимый объект, которому выделены системные ресурсы (например, процессорное время и память). Каждый процесс выполняется в отдельном адресном пространстве: один процесс не может получить доступ к переменным и структурам данных другого. Если процесс хочет получить доступ к чужим ресурсам, необходимо использовать межпроцессное взаимодействие. Это могут быть конвейеры, файлы, каналы связи между компьютерами и многое другое.

Поток использует то же самое пространства стека, что и процесс, а множество потоков совместно используют данные своих состояний. Как правило, каждый поток может работать (читать и писать) с одной и той же областью памяти, в отличие от процессов, которые не могут просто так получить доступ к памяти другого процесса. У каждого потока есть собственные регистры и собственный стек, но другие потоки могут их использовать.

Поток — определенный способ выполнения процесса. Когда один поток изменяет ресурс процесса, это изменение сразу же становится видно другим потокам этого процесса.

[Источник](https://tproger.ru/problems/what-is-the-difference-between-threads-and-processes/)

Первая ссылка в гугле. Неужели это так трудно.